# npm Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: kali-linux

I get the following error when I try to run npm command

```
root@localhost:# npm --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module &apos;semver&apos;
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
Aborted
```

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing npm and nodejs, but i still get the error

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5):

1. I manually uninstalled `node` and `npm`:

   ```bash
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node* ; sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node* ; sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*

   sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
   ```
2. I re-installed `node` and `npm` manually by downloading from [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/):

   ```bash
   tar -xf node-v5.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
     sudo mv node-v5.9.0-linux-x64/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
     sudo mv node-v5.9.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/

   # Verify installation:
     node -v ; npm -v
   ```